# MVC : Clear model value after Ajax.Beginform has been submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, model, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax

I have this model :

```
public class VehiculeModalViewModel
{
    public VehiculeModalViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Nouveau véhicule";
        TextToDisplay = "Nom du nouveau véhicule :";
    }
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Remote("IsVehiculeExists", "Defaults", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Ce véhicule existe déjà.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TextToDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

And I Use a Partial View as a modal Form (Here is just the binding code)

```
@model MultiRetouchesService.VehiculeModalViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Title)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TextToDisplay)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

From the main view I'm using Ajax.Begin form helper to call the controller method and update another partial view.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateNewVehicule", "Defaults", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "vehiculesList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace },new { Id = "vehiculeForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    Html.RenderPartial("_ModalForm", Model.VehiculeModalViewModel);
}
```

And here is the controller method (basically create a vehicule and update the other partial view):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult CreateNewVehicule(VehiculeModalViewModel vehicule)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Vehicule newVehicule =  _vehiculeService.CreateNewVehicule(vehicule.Name);
    }
    IEnumerable<Vehicule> allVehicules = _vehiculeService.GetAllVehicules();
    return PartialView("_VehiculesList", allVehicules);
}
```

If the modal is validated (client-side and remote), i'm creating the new vehicule, and after that i'm closing the modal form. It is what I want.

But, if I reopen the modal, the `Textbox` field still contains the last entered `name`.

How to avoid that ?

Following Stephen remarks, I added these line :

```
$("#submitVehicule").click(function () {
    if ($('#vehiculeForm').valid()) {
        $('#closeVehicule').click();
        $('#vehiculeForm')[0].reset();
        var form = $('#vehiculeForm');
        form.data('validator', null);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    }
})
```

Comment: Use javascript to clear it - `$('#Name').val('');` or you can reset the form using `$('#vehiculeForm')[0].reset()`

Comment: Reseting the form doesn't work. But I added an `id` to the textbox and now I'm to able to clear it with `$('#testTxt').val('');`. But now, when I reopen, I get the validation message to inform that data is missing. Do you have a suggesion?

Comment: I haven(t seen the [0]. It's reseting but same validation message after

Comment: You can always re-parse the `$.validator` - `var form = $('#vehiculeForm'); form.data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);`

Comment: doesn't seem to work, before or after resetting. No error in console.

Comment: Yes it works, but you should not be getting a validation error anyway, so there is something else you are doing causing that.

Comment: I have edited the question. All the code is here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180732/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-manta).